# What am I, falling from the sky? Another riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

You to my is falling from the sky,
You to my left has hit the ground.

What is "you to my left"?

(and "you to my")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe the answers are

What is "you to my left"?

> you to my left → me to your right → **meteorite**
>  ... has hit the ground → A meteorite has survived through the atmosphere and hit the ground

and "you to my"

> you to my → me to you(r) → **meteor**
>  ... is falling from the sky → is observed as it burns up in the Earth's atmosphere

Comment: Nice one, that's it. I thought of this riddle years ago and had never had a place to test it out until now. Good work mate!

Comment: Your shining star of a puzzle illuminated my morning atmosphere - it was wellCOME Tdt :)